# how to use ajax response data in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, response

I am having problem with response data. I want to use response data in my php file. I want to assign them to a php variable.

here is the ajax code in insert.php file.

```
function change(){
    var tp=$('#choose').val();
    var country_val=$('#country_filter').val();
    //alert(country_val);
    //var country_val=$('#country_filter').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "filter.php",
            data: { name: tp, country:"test"},

        success:function( data ) {
          alert(data);
            }

        });
     }
```

here is php code in filter.php

```
if($_REQUEST["name"]){
 $lvl = $_REQUEST["name"];
 //global $lvl;
echo $lvl;
}
```

Now I want to use the response data to be assigned to a php variable in insert.php file. How may I do that? 
Please help.

Comment: it comes from filter.php and I want to use this data in my insert.php file(I am getting response in insert.php file).

Comment: I don't think you can assign an ajax response to a "php variable"... By the time ajax runs, you're not on the server side anymore, there is not any php involved anymore in insert.php

Answer (score 1):

Send the data to insert.php file using ajax, instead of alerting it.

change success function to

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "filter.php",
 data: { name: tp, country:"test"},


  success:function(response) {
    var res = response;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: { res: res },

    success:function(data){
      alert(data);
      }
   });
});
```

In insert.php,

use this to get the variable.

```
$var = $_POST['res'];
```

Comment: Hi Optimus, your way looks great but what i want to use this value in 3rd php file (which has all client side codes). Extended your answer as a question to get value in 3rd php file. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345932/use-client-side-values-in-2nd-php-file-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

If insert.php calls filter.php with ajax and then returns a value. you cannot apply that javascript var to a php var in the insert.php. That is because the Php script runs on the server when the page is loaded, and the javascript runs locally on the users computer. To apply anything to a php variable you will have to reload the page.