# Use client side values in second php file via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have three php files.

```
filter.php - to send Ajax request and get response
insert.php - to store Ajax response
getResponse.php - to use stored Ajax response.
```

Primary purpose of doing all these thing is to use client side values using PHP code because server and client can't exchange variable values each other.

Expected: Response should be stored in php variable in getResponse.php.

I got array response in insert.php but how can I use in getResponse.php?

For e.g.

---------- filter.php ----------

```
<script>
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "filter.php",
 data: { name: tp, country:"test"},


  success:function(response) {
    var res = response;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: { res: res },

    success:function(data){
      alert(data);
      }
   });
});
<script>
```

-------- insert.php ----------

```
if ($_POST) {

    if ($_POST['id1'] !== "") {

        echo $_POST['id1'];

    }

}
```

-------- getResponse.php ----------

Code to get array response from Ajax via filter.php and insert.php.

Need to store these array value and do manipulation accordingly.

Comment: You cannot store values in a PHP file. You should be using XML or databases to store values. If you need the variable in the third file, you should directly post it to the third file instead of `insert.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
<script>

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "filter.php",
  data: { name: tp, country:"test"},

  success:function(response) {
   var res = response;
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getResponse.php",
    data: { res: res },
     success:function(data){
      alert(data);
     }
  });
});

</script>
```